# Can't see ipod, even in lsusb output

Tags: usb, mount, ipod

Just installed 11.10 64-bit
Hooked up ipod touch 2nd gen, and nothing. OS doesn't attempt to mount it, and opening a terminal and running lsusb results in it listing every device connected to my USB ports, except the ipod. I have tried different ports, and confirmed that the cable works by charging through a Wall USB adaptor. Need some help here guys

Hardware:
Mobo: ASUS M4a78-e
HDD: WD Velociraptor 300 GB 10k RPM
VGA: ATi Radeon HD 5870

LSUSB Results:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:0992 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Communicate Deluxe

Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c048 Logitech, Inc. G9 Laser Mouse

Bus 004 Device 003: ID 06a3:0728 Saitek PLC 

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:0a17 Logitech, Inc. G330 Headset
```

dmesg | tail output is:

```
[   13.788440] cfg80211:     (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   13.788441] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[   15.599944] EXT4-fs (sdb5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=0
[   24.080024] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
[   25.120004] ehci_hcd 0000:00:12.2: force halt; handshake ffffc9000064a824 00004000 00000000 -> -110
[   25.120004] ehci_hcd 0000:00:12.2: HC died; cleaning up
[   25.120013] cannot submit datapipe for urb 1, error -19: no device
[   25.120571] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   25.120752] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[   26.164037] timeout: still 1 active urbs..'
```

Comment: Can you test that a different computer can see or mount it? The device is supported and should work no problem. Testing that it will charge does not guarantee the data pins are working, but it's a good indication at least.

Comment: It worked on my win7 machine (same pc, i just put 11.10 on it) and on my Acer Aspire 1 ZG5 Netbook, which is running 10.10, which i tested just now

Comment: booting while the iPod is connected results in the ipod confirming its hooked and charging, but once the OS loads it ceases charging and starts running off of battery (only reproducible on the 11.10 desktop)

Comment: after you plug in your ipod, what is the output of `dmesg|tail`?

Comment: added dmesg | tail outputs, but everything's resolved now

Answer (score 1):

From the OP:

> I ran into a separate issue with the bootloader and win7 on the other partition, so I had to repartition and reinstall both OSes. This time I pulled my secondary HDD I use for storage (this resolved the bootloader issue), and made sure I had my ipod connected while the Live CD ran the installer. Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

I had an Ipod long time ago and it had two modes. Itune and mass storage. I don't know if ubuntu can recognize the "itune mode".
Try to switch it with itune on another computer.

Comment: Resolved.

I ran into a separate issue with the bootloader and win7 on the other partition, so I had to repartition and reinstall both OSes. This time I pulled my secondary HDD I use for storage (this resolved the bootloader issue), and made sure I had my ipod connected while the Live CD ran the installer. Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen a few times on my iPod shuffle, and in all cases it was solved by resetting the device.  Apple maintains a page for how to do this here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1320